# How to put two millisec convert dates in my code

Tags: flutter, datetime

Is this way of coding correct, and how do show 2 dates. Can someone help me to check and correct my coding? int ts=1646274840000; int ts2=1646015654686;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'api_service.dart';

class AppoinmentList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? token;
  AppoinmentList({
    Key? key,
    this.token
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppoinmentListState createState() => _AppoinmentListState();
}

class _AppoinmentListState extends State<AppoinmentList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    APIService.getAppointmentList(widget.token!);
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Appointment Listing"),
      ),
      body: _time()
      
    ); 
      //body: _appoinmentListUI(),
  }
}
      _time() {
        
        int ts=1646274840000;
        int ts2=1646015654686;
        

        DateTime tsdate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts);
        DateTime ts2date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts2);
        String fdatetime = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(tsdate);
        String fdatetime2 = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(ts2date);
    return Container(
child: Text(fdatetime,),

);

}
```

I only success to show the output for one date only. How to show two dates? Someone can help me.

This output show for one date only

[image: This output show for one date only]

Answer (score 0):

`_time()` only returns one `Text` widget for the first date. You need to add another one for the second date.

Put both `Text` widgets in a [`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) if you want them on top of each other.
like this:

```dart
_time() {
  int ts = 1646274840000;
  int ts2 = 1646015654686;

  DateTime tsdate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts);
  DateTime ts2date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts2);
  String fdatetime = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(tsdate);
  String fdatetime2 = DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm a').format(ts2date);

  return Column(
    // To make children align to the left of the screen
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

    // to prevent `Column` from expanding.
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

    children: [
      Text(fdatetime),
      Text(fdatetime2),
    ],
  );
}
```